# Why does a parabola curve share an equation with the area of a square?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Probably, $y = x^2$ plots a parabola only given certain assumptions that structure a cartesian coordinate plane, and it does not plot a parabola in e.g. the polar coordinate plane.

Now, why exactly does a parabola share an equation with the area of a square? 'Why' here is to be understood as inquiring at the equation's suggestion of a -geometrical- correspondence between the two given certain assumptions, but only the equation suggests this and not the actual shapes. Is this completely accidental, i.e., does the geometry of a parabola have nothing to do with that of a square, or does the equation $y = x^2$ indeed suggests some sort of relationship between the two shapes?

Most of all, I want to know: can we manage to identify any geometrical correspondence between a square and a parabola due to the equation?

(The equation of a circle in cartesian coordinates similarly bothers me, but at least we can speak of some sort of relationship between pythagorean triples.)

Comment: What is a "parabola"?  What is a "square"?  What does "area" mean?  Okay, a square is rectangle where the four sides are equal, and area is measured in square units so a square with side $x$ will have area of $x \cdot x=x^2$. And we note that area does *not* increase linearly; it increases geometrically.  But what on *earth* is a "parabola"?  The *only* definition *I* know is that a parabola is a curve that *by* definition increases geometricaly as a square.

Comment: @fleablood a typical definition of the parabola is as a conic section

Comment: @shintuku In this case you want to take the definition of the parabola as the set of points equidistant from a point and a line.

Comment: Loci of points equal distance from focus and directrix define a parabola. Then use Pythagoras theorem..

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/7BMm2LLVAhtgS7Ti8

Comment: @Karl Thank you very much. This finally made it click after days of being unable to formulate my question properly. Cheers!

Comment: @JohnDouma Thank you very much for the same reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the graph of $y = x$, the region under the graph between $0$ and $t$ is half of a square of side length $t$, and $\int_0^t x \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{t^2}{2}$. So some sort of answer is "because the gradient of the parabola is linear and thus carves out half a rectangle".

Answer (score 0):

The parabola
is the graph of a function
which plots the square of
the ordinate.
That happens to be
the same as the function
with gives the area
of a square given the side.

The name should
give you a hint why.

Comment: The hint is that the area of a square is a square of the segment? Sorry if I missed something

Answer (score 0):

`y = x * x` says `To compute the number y, multiply the number x with itself.`

If you're talking about length, that corresponds to area of a square.

If you're talking about real numbers, you get a parabola curve.

If you're talking about complex numbers or some other set, you may get something else.

In other words, it depends on how you define "number" (what set of numbers you're working with) and how you define "multiply" (presumably repetitive addition, which assumes you have a definition of "addition").